# Delete Trigger works, but client still shows deletion

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a "instead of delete" trigger, which "ignores" the deletion of certain records (so, in effect, some records cannot be deleted).  So far, this works very good.

Now, I'm connecting to the table via a linked table in MS Access. If I delete the records there, then Access removes them and thus "shows" them as deleted. Only when I refresh the table, then the ignored records appear again.

So finally the trigger works, but the user gets wrong feedback. Can the delete trigger somehow be rewritten such that MS Access knows that the record cannot be deleted?

The trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig ON  tblX
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM tblX 
    WHERE IDField IN 
    (
        SELECT IDField
        FROM deleted
        WHERE (...conditions...)
    );

END
```

Comment: If you perhaps provide us with the code you are using now?

Comment: Basically you are saying, you have a table opened for view in Ms Access and deleting records in the SQL Server. Ms Access will show the records as #Deleted unless you refresh/Requery the view? why dont you use the After deletion event in access form and put the code me.requery/refresh?

Comment: @krishKM No, Access does NOT show it as #Deleted, it visually removes the record (so for the user, it looks like the record "really" has been deleted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete a record in Access, Access seems to perform this deletion immediately in the user interface (e.g. the table grid you are viewing) to provide you with immediate visual feedback. It sends the delete-command to SQL Server, but does not refresh its underlying RecordSet. So Access has no way of knowing that SQL Server did not perform the delete after all.

Your only solution is to programmatically/manually trigger a requery of the data you are viewing (= refresh the underlying RecordSet) after deletion, as krish KM suggests. As far as I know, this is only possible when viewing the data in a form, not when opening the table itself.

Comment: Well, if there is no other solution, then I will do the refresh. But is there a way that the trigger communicates back to MS Access (like firing an error?). But of course, in the case that multiple records are deleted in a batch, then the error should only be fired for those records where deletion is denied.